# What conventional databases can we use to store blockchain data? Or can't we?

Tags: database, database-design, blockchain

What conventional databases can we use to store blockchain data? Or can't we?
I have a question regarding the statement "the Blockchain is the database": if I were to store a table with emails and ages, I can pick a DB like MySQL. I thought blockchain data is nothing special except every record refers to the hash of another, something like:

```
block 1: {email: "foo", age: 5, previousHash: "xyzxyz..."}
block 2: {email: "bar", age: 9, previousHash: "abcabc..."}
```

Questions:
Can we not simply use a MySQL DB, with columns (email, age, previousHash)?
2. Of course blockchain design should not be editable or deletable. Does this mean that if we use MySQL, we must not expose a web API endpoint for users to edit? (i.e. the admin on the server can still edit & delete) ?
3. Follow-up on question 2: are there currently databases already that are simply "insertable & readable only (NOT allow edit/delete)"?

A similar question was here but not detailed enough: [Can blockchain be stored in SQL or even noSQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48418461/can-blockchain-be-stored-in-sql-or-even-nosql-database)

Comment: blockchain is a data structure, it can be stored however you want.

Comment: Thanks. It's crazy difficult to find a clear explanation like yours. Do you also know how we can implement code that allows me to check if a record is consistent to that that in all (or at least 51% times all) other copies? @JBaczuk

Comment: I don't think you want to do that. How will you know how many other copies there are?

Comment: @JBaczuk, I agree it would be a bad idea. Essentially, I'm asking: what do we need to do to be confident that a record I am reading from one computer node is consistent with the clones on other nodes? More specifically, do I get record first, then check its consistency next? Or do I build a system that guarantees all nodes clone records properly first, then by the time I read, I can simply trust what I read is legit?

Comment: @JBaczuk, FYI, there is a way to know the number of peers in the network indeed. On the other hand, it still would be an awful idea to check every time; it is also prone to hacks (e.g. there are 5 legit participating computers keeping data copies honestly. Now a hacker sets up 100 more dishonest computers with fake data. There, I could be fooled to believe the fake data held by the evil majority).

Comment: In an open, permissionless network, there is no way to know how many nodes there are (what if they don't accept incoming connections?). This problem is solved by proof of work. No need to trust, just verify. Proof of work is required because a sybil attack tricks nodes into thinking they have the data that is used by the majority.

Comment: @JBaczukPlease correct me if I'm wrong: PoW, in plain language, means that computers all try to guess a solution to a hash puzzle (a puzzle which has NOTHING to do with the data that will be proposed to the network). When a computer (usually a strong one) first finds a solution (a solution that can be quickly verified by all other computers), it is then trusted to broadcast a new record to all computers. <--If this description is correct, here's the question: a evil yet strong computer now finds a solution and is granted trust, why cannot it broadcast FAKE DATA out?

Comment: That's correct except you are missing the part where nodes validate the data that was hashed. They do not blindly accept whatever data they receive based on the hash alone. If the transactions are invalid, missing proper signatures, or any of the other agreed upon consensus rules, then the nodes reject the new block, and the miner just wasted their resources mining that new block. Miners would quickly realize this is a waste of money or try to fork to a new chain.